# Window Service Application, Exchange Web Services, EWS error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, exchangewebservices

When compiling a Visual Studio 2010 source code from an existing project in Visual Studio 2015 I get this error:

CS0012 The type 'ExchangeService' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=344fslr343344ff244'

Try adding the needed assembly but i can not find what assembly to add try different ones nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web and found similar issue but not the same so I post my specific issue here with attachment of the error and how to solve it.

To solve it i upgraded EWS version 1.2.0 to EWS version 2.2 in Visual Studio 2015 and I found version 2.2 via Nuget package manager please also see attachments.

Source: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/129706

Done.

- error image:

[image: this is the error]

- resolution image:

[image: this is the solution by updating ews to version 2.2]

Done.

Answer (score 0):

attached is latest update for a newer version of Visual Studio 2019 and Exchange Web Services version 2.2.0

[image]

*** DO NOT USE THIS LIBRARY AS IN BELOW ATTACHMENT - download it here if you dont already have it or from VS integrated https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/

[image]